# Any possible way to add \pageref in \endnotetext[\pagref{...}] or \endnote[\pageref{...}]

Tags: page-numbering, endnotes

Is there any possible way to add \pageref in `\endnote` or `\endnotetext` .e.g,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\begin{document}

Text....\endnote[\pageref{page1]{\label{page1}....} or \endnotetext[\pageref{page1]{\label{page1}....}

\end{document}
```

I've tried with `\endnote[\protect\pageref{...}]{...text...}` but it produced some errors...

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) has its own version of endnotes, called pagenotes so as not to clash with the `endnotes` package.

```
% endnoteprob.tex  SE 618338

\documentclass{memoir}
\notepageref
\makepagenote
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

Some text \pagenote{An endnote}

\section{A section}

More text \pagenote{An endnote in a section}

\chapter{Second}

Yet more text \pagenote{Another endnote}

\printpagenotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

The class provides many ways of changing the typesetting of the Notes.

Comment: Thanks but note that I'm using customised class file completely based on book.cls file so changing to memoir is taking too much time ... Please advise based on book.cls

Comment: @MadyYuvi If you continue to use the `book` class then you need help on the `endnotes` package which I have never used.